# How to Preserve pagination status - Display tag

Tags: struts2, pagination, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am not using the DisplayTag library 1.2 which has inbuilt attribute called "keepStatus" which when set to true, will keep the last viewed page no. in session, so that when user returns back to this displayTag table, he should directly be shown the last viewed page instead of the default 1st page.

I am using struts2 for my application. Can someone please let me know how we can implement this feature programatically in our application.

Comment: There are only 2 parameters needed to page: start and length, pass them as request parameters.

Comment: Did this make sense to you, have you got it working?

Comment: Returns back using a browser history or somehow else?